# Dont know where to add new activity

Tags: android, android-layout

Although there are numrous examples of this problem on this forum, I still cant find the appropriate place to start a new Activity.

Heres my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen1);

    final EditText milein = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.milein);
    final EditText zipin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.zipin);
    final EditText mileout = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mileout);
    final EditText zipout = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.zipout);
    final ToggleButton checkinbutton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.checkinbutton);
    final Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);

    /** Boolean for Sharedpreferences */
    final SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean tgpref = preferences.getBoolean("tgpref", false);
    checkinbutton.setChecked(tgpref);

    /** ToggleButton Check-IN */
    checkinbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (checkinbutton.isChecked()) {
                milein.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                zipin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mileout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                zipout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                submit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                /**
                 * <-- Boolean Preferences for Checkinbutton ToggleButton
                 * Checked
                 */
                editor.putBoolean("tgpref", true);
                editor.commit();

            } else {

                milein.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                zipin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mileout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                zipout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                submit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                /**
                 * <-- Boolean Preferences for Checkinbutton ToggleButton
                 * UnChecked
                 */
                editor.putBoolean("tgpref", false);
                editor.commit();

                /** AlertDialog Button Configurations */

                final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        screen1.this).create();
                alertDialog.setMessage("Check-Out?");
                alertDialog.setButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                            }

                        });
                alertDialog.setButton2("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                checkinbutton.setChecked(true);
                                milein.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                zipin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                mileout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                zipout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        };
    });
}


public void onClick(View v) {

    }

}
```

Ive tried to implement a new screen activity just about everywhere but still cant quite get it.
any help on suggesting where it should go would be MUCH appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please give us a little more info on your problem. What happens when you run your application? Have you added your activity to your AndroidManifest? Have you set up a launcher activity?

Comment: Yes, Ive added my activity in the manifest. I know the activity is valid because, while i was experimenting on where to implement the new activity, I do notice the ToggleButton does send me to the new activity, sometimes. However, I dont want the new activty to start when I press the toggle button, I want the new Activity to open when I Press on the "status Button" (status button not shown in the code I provided) I guess my question simplified is, where do I add the "status button" to start the new activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to change activities at the end of your onClick methods.  You'll actually want to include two, one at the end of each conditional in your onClick method.

At the end of the condition, just add this code:

```
startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class));
CurrentActivity.this.finish();
```

Also, make sure you add you new activity to your Manifest file:

```
<activity
    android:name=".NewActivity"
    android:label="@string/newActivityTitle" >
</activity>
```

Once your code gets to the end of each conditional, if the new activity is setup right, the new activity should take over.

db

Comment: You are very close to helping me out, cybler. What I mean is, in my layout, I have two buttons, a ToggleButton, and a Button. I want the Button to execute the new Activity. I've tried   statusbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
 startActivity(new Intent(screen1.this,statuspage.class));
  screen1.this.finish();      I just dont know where it should go

Comment: I just figured it out. Took me about 3 hours and now I just realized how stupid of a mistake it was. The most difficult questions are sometimes the most obvious answers .